# How to remove new of line in ruby variable created from system script

Tags: ruby, regex, shell, chef-infra, end-of-line

I used chef for automation.

In one of my scenarios I need to extract a version number of passenger from rvm installed in my system.

I used 'pasver' variable for this:

```
pasver = `/usr/local/rvm/bin/gem list | grep passenger`.sub /.*\((.*)\).*/, '\1'
```

But If I use this variable, in this case:

```
if ! ::File.exists?("/usr/local/rvm/gems/#{node['redmine']['rubyversion']}/gems/passenger-#{pasver}/buildout/apache2/mod_passenger.so") then
```

Then this condition is always false, and code in if block does not run.

This is because pasver variable contains new of line.

How I can remove this new of line ?

I used next way, but without successfully:

```
pasver = `/usr/local/rvm/bin/gem list | grep passenger`.sub /.*\((.*)\).*/, '\1'.gsub("\n",'')
```

Comment: Please, mark a relevant answer if you found one.

Comment: I mark my answer - last answer in this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Chef-users mailing list suggested to me a solution for regexp

   pasver = `/usr/local/rvm/bin/gem list | grep passenger`.sub /.*((.*)).*/m, '\1'
2. But It is not all, there was a problem with using this code in erb template itself.
   Variable value disappears, but I don'k know why.

For example this code isn't worked.

```
 <% pasver = `/usr/local/rvm/bin/gem list | grep passenger`.sub /.*\((.*)\).*/, '\1'.chomp %>
    PassengerRoot <%= "/usr/local/rvm/gems/#{node['redmine']['rubyversion']}/gems/passenger-#{pasver.chomp!}" %>
    PassengerDefaultRuby /usr/local/rvm/wrappers/<%= node['redmine']['rubyversion']%>/ruby
```

This file generates:

```
    LoadModule passenger_module /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/passenger-4.0.19
    /buildout/apache2/mod_passenger.so
```

I don't get strange behaviour in IRB never. But chef runtime is something else.

My solution is using variables in recipe and then pass it to template resource:

```
template ".." do
variables ({
:pasver => pasver
})
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not use

```
pasver.chomp!
```

after the system call or,

```
if ! ::File.exists?("/usr/local/rvm/gems/#{node['redmine']['rubyversion']}/gems/passenger-#{pasver.chomp}/buildout/apache2/mod_passenger.so") then
```

Comment: This did not help! Because of chef features may be.

Comment: I Use similar syntax in ERB template, but You recipe did not it. See my code in other file: <% pasver = `/usr/local/rvm/bin/gem list | grep passenger`.sub /.*\((.*)\).*/, '\1'.chomp %>
PassengerRoot <%= "/usr/local/rvm/gems/#{node['redmine']`['rubyversion']}/gems/passenger-#{pasver.chomp!}" %>
PassengerDefaultRuby /usr/local/rvm/wrappers/<%= node['redmine']`['rubyversion']%>/ruby

Comment: I would guess the problem is *not* `chomp`, itself, but something else in your implementation.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
irb> require 'rubygems'
irb> g = Gem::Specification.find_all_by_name 'passenger'
irb> g.first.version.version
=> "4.0.19"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use rstrip() on any string to remove trailing whitespace.